# Routing between two components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React. I'm trying to learn react-router. What I'm trying to do is have two components link to each other like so:

Here is the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import About from './About';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,  Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={About}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router> 
    );
  }
}
   
export default App;
```

The About.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,  Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class About extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Router>  
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' render={() => 
                    <div>
                        <Link to={'/home'}>Hello</Link>
                    </div>}/>
                    <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router> 
        );
    }
}

export default About;
```

and the Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import About from './About';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,  Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
    ender () {
        return (
            <Router>  
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/home' render={() => 
                    <div>
                        <Link to={'/'}>Hi</Link>
                    </div>}/>
                    <Route path='/' component={About}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router> 
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

When I start the app, the About component gets rendered. However, when I click the link, the URL changes but the Home components does not get rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice to have your routing logic at one place, in this case in `App.js`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,  Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/' component={About}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router> 
    );
  }
}
   
export default App;
```

and then in Home.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>This is home component</h1>
               <Link to={'/'}>Go to About Component</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

and in About.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class About extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>This is About component</h1>
               <Link to={'/home'}>Go to Home Component</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default About;
```